Sums involving reciprocal of primes
I am interested in obtaining an upper bound for
$$
\sum_{j=1}^N 1/p_j
$$
and upper+ lower bound for
$$
\sum_{p|K} 1/p.
$$
Here $p_j$ is the j-th prime and $p$ is prime.
I was able to find an asymptotics for $\sum_{p < n} 1/p$ but I couldn't find for these variants. Any reference would be appreciated. Thank you!

For the first one, we can simply use the fact that the $N$th prime is asymptotic to $N\log N$ to deduce that
$$
\sum_{j=1}^N \frac1{p_j} = \sum_{p\le p_N} \frac1p \sim \log\log p_N \sim \log\log(N\log N) \sim \log\log N.
$$
For the second one, first assume that $K_z = \prod_{p\le z} p$ is a primorial. Then
$$
\sum_{p\mid K_z} \frac1p = \sum_{p\le z} \frac1p \sim \log\log z;
$$
but $\log K_z = \sum_{p\le z} \log p \sim z$ by the prime number theorem, and so
$$
\sum_{p\mid K_z} \frac1p \sim \log\log z \sim \log\log\log K_z.
$$
This asymptotic for primorials implies an upper bound for all $K$: if we choose $z$ so that $\pi(z)$ equals the number of prime factors of $K$, then $K_z \le K$ (since the primes dividing $K$ have been “shrunk” to become the primes dividing $K_z$), and similarly
$$
\sum_{p\mid K} \frac1p \le \sum_{p\mid K_z} \frac1p \sim \log\log\log K_z \le \log\log\log K.
$$
(Of course there's no asymptotic formula for $\sum_{p\mid K} \frac1p$, since for example it tends to $0$ when $K$ is prime.) This method is the same as the one that establishes an upper bound for the function $\omega(n)$ that counts distinct prime divisors of $n$.

To be pedantic, these are not upper or lower bounds yet.

The OP would need to clarify the question if asymptotic bounds are insufficient for their needs.

By Rosser's theorem $p_j  > j\log j$. Hence $$
\sum_{j = 1}^N \frac{1}{p_j} = \frac{5}{6} + \sum_{j = 3}^N \frac{1}{j \log j} \le \frac{5}{6} + \sum_{j = 3}^N \int_{j - 1}^j \frac{{\rm d}t}{t \log t} = \frac{5}{6} + \int_2^N \frac{{\rm d}t}{t \log t} \= \log \log N - \log \log 2 + \frac{5}{6} < \log \log N + 1.2
$$ for any $N\ge 2$.

Thank you very much for the answer!!
